# Why are elements not getting pushed into the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, scope

I've the following piece of code in a `react-native` application.

`responseJson` is what I get from API call.

The problem in the below code is that the elements that I push into `resultJson` don't exist outside the `map` function call i.e., `resultJson` remains empty only even though inside the `map` calls `resultJson` does get updated. `quaterly` is an array, but its value gets retained after the `map` call. I've added static data for `responseJson`.

What's wrong in the code below?

```js
    let responseJson = { "Q1-2018": [ { "total_rows": 742, "avg_price": "2776280.6469", "avg_sqft_price": "1592.5728", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "ACT" }, { "total_rows": 133, "avg_price": "1381205.4436", "avg_sqft_price": "974.9925", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOR" }, { "total_rows": 147, "avg_price": "1730154.9524", "avg_sqft_price": "1472.4966", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOU" }, { "total_rows": 580, "avg_price": "1797097.3069", "avg_sqft_price": "2043.7190", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "TRA" }, { "total_rows": 61, "avg_price": "4075409.8361", "avg_sqft_price": "1415.8033", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "VAL" } ], "Q2-2018": [ { "total_rows": 1090, "avg_price": "2585032.2220", "avg_sqft_price": "1578.9303", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "ACT" }, { "total_rows": 199, "avg_price": "1426902.3769", "avg_sqft_price": "1060.0000", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOR" }, { "total_rows": 84, "avg_price": "1900348.8214", "avg_sqft_price": "1332.6071", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOU" }, { "total_rows": 638, "avg_price": "1810675.6536", "avg_sqft_price": "1681.9812", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "TRA" }, { "total_rows": 60, "avg_price": "2908750.0000", "avg_sqft_price": "1458.7667", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "VAL" } ], "Q3-2018": [ { "total_rows": 971, "avg_price": "2562323.0505", "avg_sqft_price": "1569.8218", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "ACT" }, { "total_rows": 192, "avg_price": "1574309.7813", "avg_sqft_price": "1175.7865", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOR" }, { "total_rows": 56, "avg_price": "1807243.6429", "avg_sqft_price": "1275.6607", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOU" }, { "total_rows": 371, "avg_price": "1629974.8113", "avg_sqft_price": "1389.6577", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "TRA" }, { "total_rows": 65, "avg_price": "1922692.3077", "avg_sqft_price": "1341.2615", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "VAL" } ], "Q4-2018": [ { "total_rows": 1426, "avg_price": "2541386.3191", "avg_sqft_price": "1527.2468", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "ACT" }, { "total_rows": 163, "avg_price": "1440970.0491", "avg_sqft_price": "952.3129", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOR" }, { "total_rows": 91, "avg_price": "1571781.8352", "avg_sqft_price": "1244.3077", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "MOU" }, { "total_rows": 429, "avg_price": "1626291.2727", "avg_sqft_price": "1434.8834", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "TRA" }, { "total_rows": 61, "avg_price": "1797540.9836", "avg_sqft_price": "1251.2623", "yr": 2018, "evidence": "VAL" } ], "Q1-2019": [ { "total_rows": 1391, "avg_price": "2755570.1855", "avg_sqft_price": "1457.6204", "yr": 2019, "evidence": "ACT" }, { "total_rows": 126, "avg_price": "1005182.1111", "avg_sqft_price": "812.4762", "yr": 2019, "evidence": "MOR" }, { "total_rows": 18, "avg_price": "1680666.6667", "avg_sqft_price": "1287.3333", "yr": 2019, "evidence": "MOU" }, { "total_rows": 362, "avg_price": "1769586.9586", "avg_sqft_price": "1506.7099", "yr": 2019, "evidence": "TRA" }, { "total_rows": 40, "avg_price": "1974375.0000", "avg_sqft_price": "1292.5500", "yr": 2019, "evidence": "VAL" }]};
    let resultJson = [];
    let avgJson = [];
    let quarterly = [];
    Object.keys(responseJson).map((value, key) => {
      quarterly.push(value);
      responseJson[value].map((value, key) => {
        const evidence = value.evidence;
        if (typeof resultJson[evidence] === "undefined") {
          resultJson[evidence] = [];
        }
        resultJson[evidence].push(value);
        console.log(
          "resultJson[evidence]",
          resultJson[evidence].length,
          resultJson[evidence]
        );
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55261080/edit) then the `[<>]` snippet editor creating a [mcve] - there is nothing react about your code

Comment: where/what is `quarterly`? without proper sample data it is impossible to reason about what is happening in your code.

Comment: You say "responseJson is what I get from API call". Does that mean all this code is in an async callback? Are you trying to access it outside of the async call?

Comment: gunna need some vars

Comment: @MarkMeyer no I'm not trying to access it outside the async call. yes, you are right it's in async callback

Comment: It's unclear if you are trying to create an object that contains a bunch of arrays or just a flat array. It seems like you should either be initializing resultJson as an object with resultJson={} or if you're trying to create a single, flat array, you should just be using resultJson.push(value)

Comment: map() is the wrong thing to use here....

Comment: @epascarello please suggest any other alternative

Comment: Code runs when quarterly is spelled correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access keys from an array as if it were an object. Somehow Javascript allows it, and does in fact store them, so you could do `console.log(resultJson["ACT"])` after and still get the value.

But it probably makes more sense to have resultJson be an object.

`let resultJson = {}`